# Send PHP mail on html button click using JavaScript onClick then redirect to new html page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to send an email when an html button is clicked then redirect to an html confirmation page. All my code is in the same php file except for the confirmation page. It redirects with no problem just doesn't send email on button click. It was working at one point but it would send the email as soon as the page loaded. I've searched the internet for days and here is what I'm currently trying:

```
<form action="confirm.html" method="post" name= "confirm">
<?php

echo('<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="this.form.submit();">');

?>
</form>

<?php

$to="mail@hello.com";
$subject= "New Application";
$message= "Name: ".$Name;
$headers= "";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo "<body onload=\"self.close();\">";


?>
```

Comment: `<body>` tag below the `<form>`? Why `echo` that `<input>`? There's no PHP in there. Should probably use AJAX. Just do the mail part with PHP on the back end. Where should we start? Learn HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and PHP.

Comment: You're echoing the opening body tag after your form?  So your form is outside the body tag?  Odd way to make a web-page...

Comment: @PHPglue Thanks, that's exactly what I'm trying to do!

Comment: I'm new at php and this is code I found online and the only thing that even came close to working.

Comment: @Mark, why not send the email on confirm.html? That could be much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to send an email when an html button is clicked then redirect to an html confirmation page.

The above code will send an email as soon as the page loads. If you want to send an email when the form has been submitted, you will need to wrap your emailing code in a post-checking block, the send a `location` header for the redirect.

You also need some named element with a value to include in the post, for example:

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Then in your PHP you can use

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Your email() code

    // Redirect to another page
    header("Location: http://example.com/confirmation.php");
    die();
} else {
    // echo/include your form here

}
```

Be sure to put this code at the top of your PHP page before any HTML has been written or else `header()` will not function correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I'm working on it now. Should I still echo the input or get rid of it?

Comment: Some people wrap the echoing of the form in a `if ( !isset($_POST['confirm'])) { ... }` block to only display it on the initial page load.

Comment: Ok I put the code you gave along with the mail code inside the if statement at the very top. How does it know to execute the email code at button click? Am I missing something? Currently the only tag name I have with "confirm" is this: <form action="confirm.html" method="post" name= "confirm">

Comment: Apologies. Wrote this on an iPhone. Yes, you need some named form element to be included in the form post. The form element name will **not** be sent. I've updated my answer with a sample.